# No of steps taken in worst case

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, loops, time-complexity

```
def program2(L):
    squares = []
    for x in L:
        for y in L:
            if x == y:
                squares.append(x*y)
    return squares
```

The no of steps taken in worst case according to me are `4*n^2 + 2` but the answer to this problem is `4*n^2 + 2 + n` and explanation is as follow

In the worst case scenario, `L` is a long list of one repeated number (i.e. `[2, 2, 2, 2, ...]`. In this case we go through the loop for `x` in `L` n times. Every time through this loop, we perform one assignment of a value to the variable `x`, then we execute the inner loop for `y` in `L` n times.

The inner loop performs one assignment of a value to the variable y. It then has one operation that is checked every time (if `x == y`). Since the WORST case is when the list is composed of identical elements, this check is always true - so the third and fourth operations (`x*y`, and list appending) are always performed. So the inner loop executes `4*n` times on each iteration of the outer loop. Thus the nested loop structure is executed `n * (4*n + 1) = 4*n**2 + n` times!

Adding in two steps (for the first assignment statement, and the return statement) we see that in the worst case, this program executes `4*n**2 + n + 2` steps.

Why we are adding + 1 (4n + 1). Cant able to understand this because no of steps executed  are `4n` (including the inner loop and no steps steps inside it).

Comment: What assumptions are you making? Is this problem supposed to be considering Python internals? As the time-complexity here would simply be O(n^2). What are you considering to be a step?

Comment: I think your teacher is overanalyzing. Tell them to also consider how multiplication occurs, and then the "steps" changes depending on that algorithm + number of digits.

Comment: In this problem we are supposed to count the no of steps performed in worst case.not complexity in asymptotic notation

Comment: What is your definition of “step”?

Comment: Step means how many times a line is executed or how many times a line runs

Comment: I think that's the strangest complexity analysis I have ever seen.

Comment: Its the problem given in the finger exercise of Intro to CS using Python by MIT at edx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the inner loop:

The `(4*n+1)` part consists of:

`4*n` -> that is, once for each y variable.

1. assigning a value to the variable y.
2. checking whether `x==y`
3. calculating `x*y`.
4. appending the value to `squares`

The `+1` part refers to the assignment of `x` for the inner loop, which is done `n` times.

And then, at the end, you add the remaining two steps already mentioned: declaring `squares` and returning it.